# Cannot update code with lorisleiva/laravel-deployer when deploying

Tags: php, laravel, continuous-deployment, cicd, autodeploy

I am quite new to laravel deployment using this CI/CD lorisleiva/laravel-deployer. I don't know why my code on server doesn't update when doing php vendor/bin/dep deploy staging while it is successfully deployed.

Here is my deploy.yaml

```
import: 
- recipe/laravel.php
config:
  application: 'application-name'
  repository: 'repo'
  remote_user: ubuntu
  base_deploy_path: '/var/www'
hosts:
   prod:
     hostname: 'ip'
     deploy_path: '{{base_deploy_path}}/{{application}}'
   staging:
     hostname: 'ip'
     deploy_path: '{{base_deploy_path}}/{{application}}-dev'
```

I wonder why is it that it don't update my code. Thanks for the help.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zBGg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

edit .dep/repo/HEAD

change branch head to desire branch.

Ex. `ref: refs/heads/branchtopull`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).